# position of element is changing after re-showing selenium element

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver

I am performing same operation for author and about anchor tags

Code to find element

```
element = driver.find_element('class_name','author')
```

Code to hide element

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'None';", element)
```

code to show element

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", element)
```

[image]

**Question**
why the author name and about element position changed after re-showing same elements?

Website Link : https://quotes.toscrape.com/

Comment: Can you share the link to the site?

Comment: @LibinThomas I have added website link in issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

block displays the element in next line. delete that property completely or use inline

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = undefined;", element)
```

or

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'inline';", element)
```

Comment: its working fine now with inline is there any limitation by using inline?

Comment: i don't think so

Answer (score 0):

The author name and the text link "*about*" are specified in two different lines. Instead of just hiding the author's line using class name, I would suggest try hiding the whole `span`
Xpath for the same will be `xpath = "/html/body/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span[2]"`

If you want to retain the text "*by*", then try specifying separate variables to find the element of the two lines and hide/unhide them individually. This should not alter the structure of the html elements.
[image]

Try this and let me know if it worked.

Comment: earlier my thought was same to hide parent element instead of individual element but i am working on writing utilities for selenium WebDriver and i got stuck here so i just want to understand why it happening

Comment: Once you add visibility to the line, add a `time.sleep` of around 2-3 minutes. Inspect the html code manually and check if there's any difference in it as compared to earlier.